# How to create a executable script on my flutter package?

Tags: flutter, dart, package, executable

I just want to create an executable script that create the proyect structure. I call this dart file `install.dart` and I want to make

```
dart run install
```

to execute this on the projects that install my package.

I create the `install.dart` and I place it in `/lib/bin`. Then on the `pubspect.yaml` I create a section executables and I tip something like this:

```
executables:
   install: lib/bin/install
```

Then I create a proyect called `example` like dart documentation said, in my package. I install my dependecy on this package but when I make `dart run install` on the shell I get the output error

```
Could not find package install or file install
```

So I don´t really know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Place the file in `bin/`, not in `lib/bin/` and then just have the executable part in your `pubspec.yaml`:

```dart
executables:
   install:
```

And then activate the executable to make it runnable from anywhere, if you package isn't published you have to activate it from path:

```dart
dart pub global activate --source path <PATH>/<YOUR_PACKAGE>
```

Now you can run it by just writing `install` in the terminal (make sure that the name doesn't clash with other binaries on your `PATH`).

To use `dart run`, stand in the directory of your package and run:

```dart
dart run <YOUR_PACKAGE>:install
```